# How to make progress indicator shown before doing its tasks?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I got one problem in my app. In this part, the progress indicator is not shown before it executes this method.

```
if (!SQLiteFunctions.IsResultCriteriaInitialized())
{
     SystemFunctions.InitializeResultCriterias();
}
```

This method is executed only first time when a user uses this app. It takes several seconds because this method has to initialize criteria in SQLite database for evaluating the result.  However, before this method, I set the progress indicator to true but it's not shown up until the above method and the rest of them has finished.

So, my question is how to show the progress indicator before it does the above method.

This is my code

```
private void submit_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(temWeight_textBox.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(temHeight_textBox.Text) ||
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(temAge_textBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Weight, height or age cannot be empty", AppResources.Warning, MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            SystemFunctions.SetProgressIndicatorProperties(true);
            SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Analyzing...";

            double userWeight = Convert.ToDouble(temWeight_textBox.Text);
            double userHeight = Convert.ToDouble(temHeight_textBox.Text);
            int userAge = Convert.ToInt32(temAge_textBox.Text);
            string userGender = temGender_picker.SelectedItem.ToString();
            Boolean userHealthInfo1 = (Boolean)temHealthInfo_checkBox1.IsChecked;
            Boolean userHealthInfo2 = (Boolean)temHealthInfo_checkBox2.IsChecked;
            Boolean userHealthInfo3 = (Boolean)temHealthInfo_checkBox3.IsChecked;
            Boolean userHealthInfo4 = (Boolean)temHealthInfo_checkBox4.IsChecked;
            Boolean userHealthInfo5 = userGender == "Female" ? (Boolean)temHealthInfo_checkBox5.IsChecked : false;

            if (!SQLiteFunctions.IsResultCriteriaInitialized())
            {
                SystemFunctions.InitializeResultCriterias();
            }
            var result = new FecesAnalyzer().analyzeData(poopColor, poopShape, painLevel, bloodAmount, userWeight, userHeight, userGender, userAge,
                userHealthInfo1, userHealthInfo2, userHealthInfo3, userHealthInfo4, userHealthInfo5, isMelena, havingMedicines);

            List<ResultAndRecommendationDictionary> serializedResult = SystemFunctions.SerializeUserResultAndRecommendationData(result);
            SessionManagement.StoreUserLastestResultsAndRecommendation(serializedResult);
            SystemFunctions.SetProgressIndicatorProperties(false);

            List<string> necessaryInfo = result["NecessaryInfo"];
            Boolean isAdditionalAskingNeeded = Convert.ToBoolean(necessaryInfo[0]);
            if (isAdditionalAskingNeeded == false)
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ResultPage.xaml?poopColor=" + poopColor + "&shape=" + poopShape + "&painLevel=" + painLevel
                + "&bloodAmount=" + bloodAmount + "&melenaResult=" + isMelena + "&havingMedicines=" + havingMedicines
                + "&userPoopStoredDateTime=" + userPoopDateTime, UriKind.Relative));
            else
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AdditionalHealthInfomation2.xaml?poopColor=" + poopColor + "&shape=" + poopShape + "&painLevel=" + painLevel
                + "&bloodAmount=" + bloodAmount + "&melenaResult=" + isMelena + "&havingMedicines=" + havingMedicines
                + "&userPoopStoredDateTime=" + userPoopDateTime, UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

Sample codes of InitializeResultCriterias() method

```
public static void InitializeResultCriterias()
    {
        // Instantiate SQLite Function
        SQLiteFunctions db_function = new SQLiteFunctions();

        // ----- Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite : Very light brown -----                   
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Very light brown", Meaning = "Lacks in fiber" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Very light brown", Meaning = "Possibly take too much fat diet" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Very light brown", Meaning = "Possible sign of liver problems or constipation" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Very light brown", Meaning = "Possible sign of diarrhea" });

        // ----- Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite : Medium brown -----
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Medium brown", Meaning = "Normal stool" });

        // ----- Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite : Black -----
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possibly eat dark colored foods" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possibly take too much iron" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possibly drink too much alcohol" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possible sign of gastric or duodenal ulcers" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possible sign of bleeding esophageal varices" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possible other types of bleeding in GI tract" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possibly take certain medications" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possible sign of abdominal pain" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possible sign of vomiting" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possible sign of diarrhea" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possible sign of weakness" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Black", Meaning = "Possible sign of dizziness" });

        // ----- Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite : Maroon -----
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Maroon", Meaning = "Possible sign of intestinal parasites or infection" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Maroon", Meaning = "Possible sign of diverticulitis" });
        db_function.InsertData(new Color_Meaning_Table_SQLite() { Name = "Maroon", Meaning = "Possible sign of irritable bowel syndrome(IBS)" });
    ........
   }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is blocking the UI, execute the method asynchronous:

```
if (!SQLiteFunctions.IsResultCriteriaInitialized())
{
    await Task.Run(() => SystemFunctions.InitializeResultCriterias());
}
```

To use `await` in your method, it needs to be marked with the `async` keyword, but you already have that in your code, so you are good to go.